# Can we extend this definition of graph of group?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be finite nonabelian group. According to Aalipour et al. (2016), they defined the enhanced power graph of $G$ as a simple undirected graph where the vertices are all elements of $G$ and two vertices, $x$ and $y$, are adjacent if $\langle x,y \rangle$  is belong to the same cyclic subgroup of $G$.

If I consider dihedral group, $D_3=\{e,a,a^2,b,ab,{a^2}b\}$. Let $x=a,y=a^2$, then  $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle a,a^2 \rangle = \{e,a,a^2\} =\langle a \rangle $, therefore it is belong to the same cyclic subgroup of $G$ and there is an edge between $a$ and $a^2$.

Now, I would like to extend this definition to the subgroup of the group: a simple undirected graph and two subgroups of $G$ that is $H$ and $K$, are adjacent if $\langle H,K \rangle$ is belong to the same cyclic subgroup of $G$.

If we look at the $D_3$, the subgroup of $G$ are $\langle e \rangle ,\langle a \rangle, \langle b \rangle, \langle ab \rangle, \langle a^2b \rangle  $.

The question is it is possible to find $\langle H,K \rangle$ that is belong to the same cyclic subgroup of $G$? It is true if I do it like this: Let $\langle H,K \rangle=\langle \langle a \rangle,  \langle a^2 \rangle \rangle=\langle a \rangle $, therefore $\langle H,K \rangle$ is belong to the same cyclic subgroup of $G$ and there is an edge between $\langle a \rangle$ and  $\langle a^2 \rangle$  ?

Comment: Your question is unclear: For **some** pairs of subgroups $H, K< G$, the subgroup $<H,K>$ they generate is cyclic and for **some** pairs it is not cyclic.

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes it is true that for some pairs it is not cyclic. But I just want to know if it is that true the way I come out with $\langle \langle a \rangle, \langle a^2 \rangle \rangle =  \langle a \rangle $?

Comment: Yes, of course, the subset $\{a, a^2\}$ generates the cyclic subgroup $<a>$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you so much. I got confused because the original one dealt with vertices but when it come to subgroups, I felt that something was wrong with it.

Comment: There is no real difference between the two definitions: $<a, b>= <<a>, <b>>$.